# Is it possible to run a Seed Job without publishing the generated jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

[Apache Beam](https://github.com/apache/beam) uses the [Jenkins Job DSL plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin) with a [seed job](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.5.0/.test-infra/jenkins/job_00_seed.groovy) responsible for generating the rest of our Jenkins jobs from groovy source files ([sample run](https://builds.apache.org/job/beam_SeedJob/2095/)).

The job definitions are authored as Groovy scripts and maintained in source control just like other source code. I would like to more easily verify changes to Jenkins job definitions during code review.

We already have the ability to run our Seed Job on a GitHub pull request, however the updated jobs get published right away and replace the existing jobs. Is it possible to run a Seed Job on Jenkins but *not* publish the generated job? Ideally it would run the Seed Job script and output the generated XML somewhere without actually committing it to Jenkins. Perhaps it could even show a diff against the existing job definition.

Comment: It would be possible. It would require a bit of work. I could take a look at this over the weekend.

Comment: @RobKielty cool, let me know how it goes!

Comment: ygm at your apache email addr